# Value === is not a member of a string

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, functional-programming, apache-spark-sql

```
val columnsToSum = privacyColumnsName.reduce((left, right) => (left)+ (right))
```

Then:

```
privacy = privacy.withColumn("Result",when(columnsToSum === privacyColumnsName.size,1).otherwise(0))
```

I get:

> Error:(111, 63) value === is not a member of String
>         privacy = privacy.withColumn("Result",when(columnsToSum === privacyColumnsName.size,1).otherwise(0))

I have tried with `==` and `equals`, the same error is thrown.

Comment: what is the datatype of privacyColumnsName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import spark implicits:

```
val spark: SparkSession = ...
import spark.implicits._
```